# Calculating New Field using Python Field Calculator From Two Fields Returning Specific Numbers

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, python-parser

I have never used the SQL function in the field calculator and need some guidance. I am attempting to calculate new field data (date update) using python for a client that will look at first at one column and then another.

I will need something that will look at column one (DateAsBuilt) and if not null will return the right four characters of that column. If DateAsBuilt is null I need the code to then look at another column (Project) and return only the left four characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a beginner, there are three important concepts to accomplish this:

1. How to use the codeblock part of the Field Calculator to write
   and call a function
2. How to test for null values
3. How to return the first or last four characters of a string

I will explain each of these concepts below.

**Item 1:** You need to check "Python" and "Show Codeblock", then write a function definition in the "Pre-Logic Script Code" box.

Here is a function definition, which should be placed in your Pre-Logic Script Code. I named this function "find":

```
   def find(dateasbuilt, project): 
      if dateasbuilt is not None: 
         return dateasbuilt[-4:]
      elif dateasbuilt is None: 
         return project[:4]
```

Then you call the function in the box below, using the function name and the fields that you need it to reference.

So your calculated value should be set to

`find( !DateAsBuilt!, !Project!)`

Here is a screen-capture:

[image: Field Calculator with the function entered]

**Item 2:** Python uses "None" to represent null. Testing for null values using Python in a text field, you must test for "is None" or "is not None" ... note that a null value is never *EQUAL TO* Null. It either "is null" or "is not null" but cannot be evaluated using the = (equals sign).

**Item 3:**  You can use Python slice notation to select the first or last four characters of a string. String[:4] will give the first four characters (up to, but not including the character at index 4, where strings are indexed starting at zero). String[-4:] will give the last four characters (all characters including and after the fourth-to-last character).

More on slice notation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation

Comment: It worked! Thanks for taking me to school on this! Much appreciated.